# How to make a Stingtokenizer for a char

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I figured out how to do it for a `String` and an `int` but I am having trouble figuring it out for `char`. When I try to compile it gives me an error that I have a string token for a `char`.

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
String name = stk.nextToken();
char sex = stk.nextToken();
int count = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.charAt(0);`

```
char sex = (stk.nextToken()).charAt(0);
```

I assume your string is something like "a b c d".

Answer (score 0):

The `nextToken()` method returns a `String`, which is not compatible with `char`. If you're certain that the token will be at least one character long, you can take the first character of the String with [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) like so:

```
char sex = stk.nextToken().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of the String, since you only allow to put 1 character in `char`.

Try something like:

```
char c = 0;

if (name.length() == 1){
    c = name.charAt(0);
}
```